# cpanel error :This feature, “”, is not enabled on your account

Tags: cpanel

[Cpanel Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBJYR.png)

how can I fix it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a coding issue. You need to contact your webhosting provider for support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually cPanel accounts are created with two separate ways to manage what functionality they have access to.

One of them is the Package - it dictates how much Disk Space your account can utilize, if it has SSH, CGI access etc..

The other one is the "Feature" list - it dictates what cPanel tools' features you have access to. Each Package that your cPanel account can use also has an assigned Feature list to it.

It seems like the Package that your cPanel account is using has a Feature list assigned to it, that doesn't allow the feature which you're trying to access - you should contact your hosting provider.

Most often they will tell you that you need to upgrade your package to access other features, etc..